# PHP Timestamp with timezone

Tags: php, timestamp

Why is my timestamp different from the original datetime in my timezone?

ex. I run the code on 4/9/17 at 8:30:51.

The result will be 4/10/17 11:30:51

```
$now = new DateTime();
now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));
echo $now->format("m/d/y G.i:s<br>");
```

Comment: Your server is in what timezone?

Comment: @JoseMarques in my desktop I'm using UTC canada

Comment: I'm talking about which web server do you use? For example Apache, windows ISS.

Comment: @JoseMarques Im using xampp

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, the date it's set to universal time zone, in your web server and most of the browsers.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Manila"));
echo $now->format("m/d/y G.i:s<br>");
```

So you use this code to parametrize your date.

DateTimeZone -> To your timezone, that I predict it to be Asia/Manila

format-> Format date to the desired format.

If it did not work, try this:

On the local server, you can change the configuration in PHP_INI.

In your file Look for:

; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions

; http://php.net/date.timezone

date.timezone = UTC

change for

; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions

; http://php.net/date.timezone

date.timezone = Asia/Manila

If this does not solve your problem. Use this in the beginning of all your PHP files.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'your_language');
```

Exemple:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
```

If you like, give a score or helpful flag.